# set_exception_handler for specific exceptions

Tags: php

I'm using a new API and I want to handle exceptions specific to it, and return the data from the exceptions to JS function that made a request. The thing is - I have a `fatal_handler` registered with `register_shutdown_function` in the program, and I want to avoid it for these exceptions, because It won't let me return the necessary data to the JS function, and I don't want to mess with this specific handler because it's more general.
I managed to override it with `set_exception_handler`, but I assume it will catch other unhandled exceptions as well.

Is there any way to define the instance of the exception (e.g `AException`) that will be handled in `set_exception_handler()`, same as in a catch block?

My only idea was to check the type of the exception object I'm getting to the handler function (with `instanceof`, and rethrow it if it's not the type I'm looking for.

Comment: Why is this tagged JS? What does this question have to do with JS?

Comment: The purpose is eventually to respond with the data of the exception to the JS function that made the POST request. It definitely related mainly to PHP functionality, but I assumed people who worked with both might have experience with such an issue @GoldenretriverYT

Comment: `set_exception_handler` and `register_shutdown_function` are for "the last resort" - show something vaguely useful when everything else is broken. Arguably, any time one of those is reached, it is a bug which needs fixing, because it should already have been caught by a `catch` statement and handled more gracefully. You seem to know that `catch` blocks exist, so I'm not clear why you're not using them.

Comment: @IMSoP the thing is I'm working on an existing project, and I'd like to return a specific response to the User in the UI, for this specific action, but it happens in multiple functions in multiple places, so I can either catch it on the place where the API request is made and then have a very complex work on returning the error back in the flow, or let the exception flow up but since the function is called from different places, I might miss some place that I should catch it and cause bugs afterwards, since I tried to avoid these I currently went with the option I described above..